# Build Virtuoso (with Mono integration) on Ubuntu: build error on libgc

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, mono, virtuoso

UPDATE: Okay, I found it on [this page](http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSBldMono): you have to run ./configure with the --enable-mono parameter. Then you'll also find out that some more dependencies are missing that aren't mentioned anywhere.

Sadly, this leaves me with another problem I cannot solve. As we still have the unfinished bounty here, let's ask this.

After doing ./autogen and ./configure --enable_mono (tried it on the code branches develop/6 and develop/7), I get the following error:

```
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../libsrc/Dk -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -DMONO_USE_EXC_TABLES -fexceptions -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -DNDEBUG -DPOINTER_64 -I/usr/local/src/virtuoso-opensource/libsrc/Xml.new -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -Dlinux -D_GNU_SOURCE -DFILE64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I../../binsrc/mono/mono-1.1.7/libgc/include -I../../libsrc -I../../libsrc/Dk -DNO_UDBC_SDK -DUSE_INCLUDED_LIBGC=1 -g -O2 -MT libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.Tpo -c sched_pthread_gc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.o
sched_pthread_gc.c:42:22: fatal error: gc_typed.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/virtuoso-opensource/libsrc/Thread'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/virtuoso-opensource/libsrc'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

[This link](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/libsrc/Thread/sched_pthread_gc.c) has the contents of the problematic file. If I remove the import for `gc_typed.h`, the next import is not found. I just did `sudo apt-get install libgc-dev` which worked. Make still gives me the same error. I believe somewhere around this file and this compilation the error is buried, but I can't fix it.

I'm a Linux noob, can somebody give me advice what might be the problem here or how to solve it?

Additional Information:
1. `ldconfig -v -p` clearly says that libgc.so exists, so why is this make script looking for the header?

```
...
libgdbm_compat.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.so.3
libgdbm.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.3
libgd.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgd.so.2
libgcrypt.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11
libgccpp.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1
libgccpp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgccpp.so
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
libgc.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgc.so.1
libgc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgc.so
libgamin-1.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgamin-1.so.0
libgailutil.so.18 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgailutil.so.18
libfuse.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libfuse.so.2
...
```

1. To install Virtuoso with Mono support, I used the following tutorials:

   - the README on the Virtuoso [GitHub page](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource)
   - I had small problems doing the exports on [this Mono-Virtuoso page](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSBldMono), might one of those be the problem?
2. Virtuoso has been working before, I just don't get Virtuoso to build with --enable-mono. Mono works well, can build and execute dlls and exes without a problem.
   .

.

.

> ORIGINAL QUESTION:
>
> I installed Virtuoso and Mono on a Ubuntu server and [using this
>   tutorial](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rthclrmono.html) compiled the sanity.cs class to a sanity.dll file. When I
>   tried importing the 'vector' I got a message:
>
> ```
> SQLState: 42001
> Message: SR185: Undefined procedure DB.DBA.import_clr.
> ```
>
> Does that mean that I put the .dll in the wrong place? Or do I have
>   the wrong version of Virtuoso installed?
>
> I used apt-get to install Virtuoso and Mono.
>
> UPDATE: Okay, the apt-get version of Virtuoso was waaay too old. The
>   OpenLink Twitter account told me that the new versions should be built
>   from the Github account.
>
> Now I built Virtuoso on Ubuntu following the readme on
>   https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource, but that doesn't
>   explain how to integrate Mono in any way.
>
> - I already made the sanity.cs Hello World file work, confirming that    Mono is setup correctly.
> - The server runs, but the Mono section in the Virtuoso.ini is empty:
>
> .
>
> ```
> [Mono]
> ;MONO_TRACE                     = Off
> ;MONO_PATH                      = <path_here>
> ;MONO_ROOT                      = <path_here>
> ;MONO_CFG_DIR                   = <path_here>
> ;virtclr.dll                    =
> ```
>
> I put the default paths in this file like this:
>
> ```
> [Mono]
> ;MONO_TRACE                     = Off
> ;MONO_PATH                      = /usr/bin/mono
> ;MONO_ROOT                      = /usr/lib/mono
> ;MONO_CFG_DIR                   = /etc/mono
> ;virtclr.dll                    =
> ```
>
> I cannot `find` a virtclr.dll on my system. How can I generate it? Can
>   someone help me with a link explaining how to integrate Mono in
>   Virtuoso or tell me how to proceed? Should I have built Virtuoso with
>   different settings?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a mess. It depends on `mono-1.1.7`, and it doesn't build it before trying to use items that it depends on; so the build is messy. I would strongly suspect that the developers are not building/testing this aspect of their project.

You need to download `mono-1.1.7` manually - this is because the location of the mono tarball is not where they think it is.; e.g. from:

```
wget -O binsrc/mono/mono-1.1.7.tar.gz ftp://ftp1.freebsd.org/mirror/FreeBSD-Archive/ports/distfiles/mono-1.1.7.tar.gz
```

if you don't have wget, then you can use curl:

```
curl -o binsrc/mono/mono-1.1.7.tar.gz ftp://ftp1.freebsd.org/mirror/FreeBSD-Archive/ports/distfiles/mono-1.1.7.tar.gz
```

run configure:

```
./configure --enable-mono
```

Swap the order of the `binsrc` and `libsrc` subdirectories in the `Makefile`:

```
sed -i 's/libsrc binsrc/binsrc libsrc/' Makefile
```

run make (use a -j option if you want to make it faster e.g. -j2):

```
make
```

The build will fail. Do not panic. Swap binsrc and libsrc **again**:

```
sed -i 's/binsrc libsrc/libsrc binsrc/' Makefile
```

and re-run make:

```
make
```

The build should succeed at this point.

Bear in mind, it uses a private copy of mono-1.1.7, and most modern linux distros use 2.0, so there could be some conflicts with this.

Comment: I deleted the whole installation, cloned the git repo again, got the old mono runtime again, did ./autogen.sh because ./configure else wouldn't run, and executed the rest of the commands you suggested. Sadly, on the 2nd run there's still an error: `..../libvirtuoso-gc-t.a(libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.o): In function `oplthread_create':
..../sched_pthread.c:424: undefined reference to `GC_pthread_create'
..../libvirtuoso-gc-t.a(libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.o): In function `thread_exit':
..../sched_pthread.c:571: undefined reference to `GC_pthread_detach'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Nevertheless +1 for your work here, guess the only option right now is giving up :-(

Comment: Mono 1.1.7????? GUYS, that is enourmosly ancient, maybe 5 years old? Please upgrade to Mono 3.x

Comment: @knocte That's what the package builds against. I don't know how much work it would be to get it to work correctly with the latest mono.

Comment: Probably much less than trying to use an ancient mono.