# libgc seems to be missing (Installing Virtuoso-Opensource with Mono support)

Tags: linux, mono, makefile, virtuoso

I'm building Virtuoso Opensource after doing `./configure --enable_mono` - works fine. Calling `make` then gives me an error, because `libgc` is not found.

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/virtuoso-opensource/libsrc/Thread'
/bin/bash ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../libsrc/Dk    -fno-strict-aliasing -O2  -DMONO_USE_EXC_TABLES -fexceptions -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall  -DNDEBUG -DPOINTER_64   -I/usr/local/src/virtuoso-opensource/libsrc/Xml.new  -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -Dlinux -D_GNU_SOURCE -DFILE64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I../../binsrc/mono/mono-1.1.7/libgc/include -I../../libsrc -I../../libsrc/Dk -DNO_UDBC_SDK -DUSE_INCLUDED_LIBGC=1 -g -O2 -MT libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.Tpo -c -o libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.lo `test -f 'sched_pthread_gc.c' || echo './'`sched_pthread_gc.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../libsrc/Dk -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -DMONO_USE_EXC_TABLES -fexceptions -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -DNDEBUG -DPOINTER_64 -I/usr/local/src/virtuoso-opensource/libsrc/Xml.new -DOPENSSL_NO_KRB5 -Dlinux -D_GNU_SOURCE -DFILE64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I../../binsrc/mono/mono-1.1.7/libgc/include -I../../libsrc -I../../libsrc/Dk -DNO_UDBC_SDK -DUSE_INCLUDED_LIBGC=1 -g -O2 -MT libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.Tpo -c sched_pthread_gc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.o
sched_pthread_gc.c:41:16: fatal error: gc.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [libthrp_gc_la-sched_pthread_gc.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/virtuoso-opensource/libsrc/Thread'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/virtuoso-opensource/libsrc'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
dellas@india672:/usr/local/src/virtuoso-opensource$
```

I just did `sudo apt-get install libgc-dev` which worked. Make still gives me the same error. I'm a Linux noob, can somebody give me advice what might be the problem here or how to solve it?

EDIT: FYI: `ldconfig -v -p` clearly says that `libgc.so` exists, so why is this `make` script looking for the header?

```
...
libgdbm_compat.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm_compat.so.3
libgdbm.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.3
libgd.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgd.so.2
libgcrypt.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11
libgccpp.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1
libgccpp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgccpp.so
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
libgc.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgc.so.1
libgc.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgc.so
libgamin-1.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libgamin-1.so.0
libgailutil.so.18 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgailutil.so.18
libfuse.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libfuse.so.2
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Virtuoso mono hosting support is for version 1.x and will not work with the current 2.x and later releases for which support needs to be schedule for addition ...

Is is specifically mono runtime support you are seeking or maybe just the ADO.Net Provider for Mono, which can be built using:

```
cd binsrc/VirtuosoClient.Net
gmake -f Makefile.mono
```

Best Regards
Hugh Williams

Answer (score 2):

You should check the contents that were provided by the `libgc-dev` package. There is generally a compatibility file in `/usr/include` called `gc.h`, who's only purpose is to `#include <gc/gc.h>`. Your distirbution may not have this file, which is causing the compilation problem.

To check the contents of `libgc-dev`, you do a:

```
dpkg-query -L libgc-dev
```

This will list all the files that were provided by this package. If it doesn't contain `/usr/include/gc.h`, then you may need to alter the `#include` to read `#include <gc/gc.h>`, or change the makefile to add: `-I/usr/include/gc`. I'd change the `-I` option as a last resort.

As an alternative, you can add a file in `/usr/include` called `gc.h` with the simple content:

```
/* This file is installed for backward compatibility. */
#include <gc/gc.h>
```

Comment: In fact something in the code I copied seemed to be wrong the actual problem can now be found in this question, it's something you might be able to answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274537/build-virtuoso-with-mono-integration-on-ubuntu-build-error-on-libgc